# Android Studio editor red warning - Suspend: Thread Log message: No

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using EventBus to pass a message from a worker thread to the UI thread in the activity, and I have to have a method called onEvent that eventbus uses, soI have this code:

```
public void onEvent(final UpdateTimelineHeaderEvent event) {
    Log.e("onEvent", "UpdateTimelineHeaderEvent");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            manageTimelineHeader(event.getData());
        }
    });

}
```

The Override line is backgrounded in pink and if I hover over the left side of the editor, I get a small yellow window that says:

```
Line 167
Suspend: Thread
Log message: No
```

Can anyone tell me what this is?

Comment: had the same with a red point, it turned out that it must have to do something with copy paste. I tried some code from a website and copied it, and then pasted it into my code. After I deleted the pasted code and write it by myself, the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Just clicking on it makes it disappear. You might have clicked on the line without being aware of it.

Whenever you click on the code editor the line gets selected for a breakpoint to be applied. You simply remove the breakpoint i.e the red button by re-clicking on it.

Refer this link for more information 
[Work with breakpoints - developer.android](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints)

Comment: Yeah but what does it mean